# visible edit text when checkbox is checked in listview

Tags: android, xml, listview

Android listview for custom listview for single row has checkbox and edittext , want disable edit text if unchecked checkbox .

```
holder. checkBox.setChecked(false);
holder. price.setText(showUserOrderses.get(position).getPrice()+" LE");
holder.count.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new       

 CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean   

     isChecked) {
         if (holder.checkBox.isChecked())
         {
             holder.count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

         }
         else if(!holder.checkBox.isChecked())
              {
                  holder.count.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              }
      }
  });
```

I want to know how to update single row il list view
as I tried that but doesn't work

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (holder.checkBox.isChecked())
            {
                 holder.count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            else
            {
                 holder.count.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

Comment: it works fine but does not remain for singl row it makes render for all list view cells

Comment: add CheckBox `android:focusable="false"`

Comment: @AsmaaShaban Read http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/11/listview-with-checkbox-single-row.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    if(holder.checkRaw.isChecked())
        holder.count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        holder.count.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your EditText? I can't found it in your code and I can sure which one is. If you want to disable EditText when CheckBox's status is unchecked, replace your code as follow

```
if (holder.checkBox.isChecked())
{
    holder.count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    edittext.setEnable(true);
}
else
{
    holder.count.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    edittext.setEnable(false);
}
```

Comment: count is the edit text .. here i used BaseAdapter  and put this code in getview method but does not work fine in run listview app.. it doest update the selected row

Comment: what are you updating when you click checkbox? Your adapter data does't changed.

Comment: the keyboard opened when do my operation on one or more cell ,, but when the keyboard closed every thing lost in cells